# Formatting range in column depending on header

Tags: excel, vba

i want to format a range in a column depending on what the header contains.

The header can look like this, "M1_211229_3_St_1" or this "M1_211229_3_St_2". Basically i want to colour format a range in the column in different colours depending on if header contains "St_1" or "St_2" in the header.

Is this possible to do ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Conditional Formatting can server purpose. Try it please.

Answer (score 0):

You can just save header value in a Variable(HeadValue) and use Right Function to save last 4 characters(St_1 or St_2) in a string, and based on the value of string, you can perform Formatting of your range.

```
HeadValue = Right(HeadVar, 4)

If HeadValue = "St_1" then
 'Formating accordingly
Elseif  HeadValue = "St_2" then
 'Formating accordingly
End if
```